# JQuery hide a button based on another button's visibility

Tags: jquery, css

I am new to JQuery.  I am trying to hide a button if another button is "display: inline" as soon as the page is loaded. When I opened the following html file on a browser I got the alert "page loaded" only. What am I missing?  Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function hideButton() {
    alert("page Loaded");
    if ($('#Email').css('display') == 'inline') {
      alert("found send email button.  Now watch the Continue button disappear.");
      $("#Continue").css({
        display: "none",
        visibility: "hidden"
      });
      $("#Continue").hide();
    }
  };
  hideButton();
});
```

```css
.sendEmailButton {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.continueButton {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>On page load the button "Continue" will display after page loaded</p>
<div> <button class="sendEmailButton" id="Email" type="button" style="display: inline;">Send Email</button></div>
<br>
<div> <button class="continueButton" id="Continue" type="button" style="display: inline;">Continue</button></div>
```

I expect the "Continue" button to disappear after the alert message "page loaded".

Comment: Debug the value of `$('#Email').css('display')` before you check it.   It's **not** `inline` when you expect it to be.  To debug either use the browser dev tools (F12, select sources, find your code, add a breakpoint) or add the keyword `debugger;` in your code (to do the same as F12 breakpoint but via code) or just add a simple `console.log($('#Email').css('display'))` after your first `alert`

Comment: As you're using [tag:jquery], try `if ($('#Email').is(":visible"))`  https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: Thank you, freedomn-m!  Both your suggestions prove to be helpful and working.  The value turns out to be "inline-block" rather then  just "inline" as the source code indicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function hideButtonCond(test, target) {
    if ($(test).is(":visible")) {
      console.log("Button " + test + ", is visible.", "Hiding " + target);
      $(target).css({
        display: "none",
        visibility: "hidden"
      }).hide();
    }
  };
  hideButtonCond("#Email", "#Continue");
});
```

```css
.sendEmailButton {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.continueButton {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>On page load the button "Continue" will display after page loaded</p>
<div> <button class="sendEmailButton" id="Email" type="button" style="display: inline;">Send Email</button></div>
<br>
<div> <button class="continueButton" id="Continue" type="button" style="display: inline;">Continue</button></div>
```

This uses `.is()` to test if the element is `visible`, a [Selector Filter](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

Comment: Thank you for providing the code example, Twisty.